# Is there any way to control OpenShift routes for co-working with horizontal pod auto-scaler?

Tags: openshift, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I'm using Horizontal Pod Autoscaler to scale my pods in an OpenShift environment. I have a web application running in pods. As the pod scales, I got an HTTP status code 404 error in the first few seconds of an HTTP request. Is this because routes is sending a request to a pod that is in the process of being launched? If so, is there any way to prevent the error? I've tried setting `router.openshift.io/haproxy.health.check.interval` to a small value, but I still can't avoid this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you did not configure your **readiness checks** correctly. [Check the documentation on how to add readiness and liveness checks to your Deployment](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/applications/application-health.html).

- A readiness probe determines if a container is ready to accept service requests.
- A liveness probe determines if a container is still running.

In newer versions of OpenShift / Kubernetes there is now also the startupProbe, which may help you in your case.

Here is an example of a Deployment with a liveness and a readiness probe:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
...
spec:
...
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example
          readinessProbe: 
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8080
          livenessProbe: 
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8080
...
```